# How to write a believable CV?

Tags: masters, application, cv

I'm having trouble writing a believable CV. I want to apply for masters degree. I'm a professional in IT industry. I have done dozens of high-tech projects. The problem is my bachelor G.P.A is low(3.2) and when I list my abilities and projects in my CV, most of readers won't believe it. I had this problem with companies when applying for job. Now I'm having this problem with universities. For example my grade in Networking course is very low(C) but I was actually a network designer in my previous jobs.

Another reason why people don't believe it is the diversity of my knowledge. I have done projects in networking, embedded systems and big data which don't relate to each other. This problem yields to rejection from universities either with low or high global rank. Unfortunately I work on very very back end side of projects which means I don't have something to present like designers. Most companies I work for don't want to give me a reference letter because some of them are military or government dependant.

How can I write a CV that is believable?

Comment: I have seen letters from the government saying to the effect "We cannot tell you exactly what <insert name here> did here, but he was amazing, and he demonstrated his skills in blah blah. For that he was awarded by ..., etc" There is no reason that your superiors cannot write a similar letter.

Comment: can you give some more context?  Are you working for Iran government contractors applying to Iranian schools, or elsewhere (I have heard a few iranians having problems getting into US schools independent of skill)?  There are many people that didnt do great in school, spent years working in industry, and did will at it.  You may also need to separate technical skills from research capability in your SOP, depending on the program you apply to.

Comment: What evidence do you have that your rejections have been because they didn't believe your CV, as opposed to some other reason?

Comment: @user1938107 I'm applying from Iran to European universities.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm asking this because I had this problem with my employers. I'm just sceptical that may be I'm facing trouble again. Because none of the universities I have applied until now didn't answered my question about the reason of rejection.

Comment: As a matter of policy, most universities never inform applicants of the reason for rejection.

Comment: In all the European universities I know, the only thing that matters when applying to a Master degree is whether your Bachelor is in the right domain and from a recognized university. All the rest is irrelevant. I have never heard of a Master program asking for employer's references since the vast majority of applicants rarely have professional experience. Your application strategy might be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to focus your CV on the specific department and specialty you are interested in.

First, look at some programs of study.  Look at the research interests.  Look at some of the published papers.  Think about which of your many areas within IT you would like to delve into more deeply; think about which areas interest you the most for working in when you are done with this next degree.

Once you've identified some programs that YOU are excited about, pick and choose which items in your full CV you'd like to emphasize in your application.

Try to get some feedback from a couple people whose opinion you trust, about your draft CV and application.

You absolutely need at least one strong letter of recommendation -- so figuring out who could write this is going to be important.

I apologize, I don't know the specific differences between the European context and the U.S., but hopefully this answer, written by someone who knows the U.S. system best, will still by helpful.